# Ember.js - doing it right (structure, includes, general questions)

Tags: ember.js, requirejs, handlebars.js

I'm playing around with ember.js and am stuck somehow finding out how to build up the structure the right way. I could follow [all examples](http://emberjs.com/guides/), but have some problems putting them all together.

I'm using require.js and handlebars.

My directory structure looks like this:

```
- app
- - controllers
- - css
- - helpers
- - lib
- - models
- - routes
- - templates
- - - partials
- - views
```

My application.js looks like this:

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery:'lib/jquery-1.7.2',
        handlebars:'lib/handlebars',
        ember:'lib/ember',
        ember_data:'lib/ember-data',
        text:'lib/requireJS/text',
        md5:'lib/md5',
        spin:'lib/spin'
    },

    shim:{
        'ember':{
            deps:[ 'jquery', 'handlebars'],
            exports:'Ember'
        },
        'ember_data':{
            deps:[ 'ember'],
            exports:'DS'
        }
    },

    waitSeconds:15        
});

define('application'
        ,[
            // Routes
            'routes/app_router'

            // Controller
            ,'controllers/application_controller'

            // Views
            ,'views/application_view'
            ,'views/category/category_list_view'

            // Libraries
            ,'jquery'
            ,'handlebars'
            ,'ember'
            ,'ember_data'
            ,'spin'

        ]
        , function (

             // Router
             Router

             // Controller
            ,ApplicationController

             // Views
            ,ApplicationView
            ,CategoryListView

             // Models
            ,Category
            ,Product
        )
    {
        return  Ember.Application.create({

             VERSION: '1.0.0'

            ,rootElement:'#main'

            // Load Router
            ,Router:Router

            // Load Controllers
            ,ApplicationController:ApplicationController

            // Load associated Views
            ,ApplicationView:ApplicationView
            ,CategoryListView:CategoryListView

            // Load Models
            ,Category:Category
            ,Product:Product

            //Persistence Layer,using default RESTAdapter in ember-data.js.
            ,store:DS.Store.create({
                revision:10
                ,adapter:DS.RESTAdapter.create({
                     bulkCommit:false
                    ,serializer:DS.Serializer.create({
                        primaryKey:function (type) {
                            return type.pk;
                        }
                    })
                    ,mappings:{
                        //categories:Category
                    }
                    ,namespace:'api'
                    ,url: "https://example.org"
                })
            })

            ,ready:function () {

            }
        });
    }
);
```

Then my application controller

```
define(
    'controllers/application_controller'
    ,['ember' ],
    function () {
        return Ember.Controller.extend({
            init: function() {
            }
        });
    }
);
```

The application view:

```
define('views/application_view', [
        'text!templates/application.html',
        'ember'
    ],
    function(Application_markup) {
        return Ember.View.extend({
            template: Ember.Handlebars.compile( Application_markup ),
            elementId: 'container',
            didInsertElement: function() {
                this.$().hide().show("slow");
            }
        });
    }
);
```

And, finally, the application.html template

```
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
        FOO BAR
    </div>

    <div id="navigation">
        {{outlet mainNavigation}}
    </div>

    <div id="content">

    </div>

    <div id="footer">

    </div>

</div>
```

What I am trying to do now is to include another template into the main application template (category_list). I guess I either have to do this in the HTML template itself, or in the application view - but in case of the latter one I don't know how to configure/parse/bind more than one template.

What is the best practice of building individual, independent, modular templates and to put them all together? Where exactly should this happen? 
Or is this even a wrong approach of using ember.js?

Maybe one of you could make some things more clear to me.
Thanks.

EDIT #1

app_router.js

```
define('routes/app_router',
    ['ember' ],
    function () {
        return  Em.Router.extend({
            enableLogging:true, //useful for development
            /*  location property:  'hash': Uses URL fragment identifiers (like #/blog/1) for routing.
             'history': Uses the browser's history.pushstate API for routing. Only works in modern browsers with pushstate support.
             'none': Does not read or set the browser URL, but still allows for routing to happen. Useful for testing.*/
            location:'hash',
            /*   location: 'history',
             rootURL:'/app',*/
            root:Ember.Route.extend({
                index:Ember.Route.extend({
                    route:'/'

                    /*,connectOutlets:function (router) {
                        //Render application View ,sign in.
                        v = router.get('applicationController').get('view');
                        if (v) v.remove();
                        App.router.get('applicationController').set('loggedin', false);

                        router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet({name:'login', outletName:'loginform'});
                        router.get('loginController').enterLogin();

                    }*/
                })
                /*,contacts:Em.Route.extend({
                    route:'/contacts',

                    showContact:function (router, event) {
                        router.transitionTo('contacts.contact.index', event.context);
                    },

                    showNewContact:function (router) {
                        router.transitionTo('contacts.newContact', {});
                    },
                    logout:function (router) {

                        jQuery.ajax({
                            url:'/site/logout',
                            type:'POST',
                            success:function (response) {
                                if (!response.authenticated) {
                                    router.get('applicationController').set('loggedin', false).get('view').remove();
                                    router.transitionTo('root.index', {});
                                }
                            }
                        })
                    },


                    index:Em.Route.extend({
                        route:'/',
                        connectOutlets:function (router) {
                            if (router.get('applicationController').get('loggedin'))
                                router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('contacts', App.store.findAll(App.Contact));
                            else   router.transitionTo('root.index');
                        }
                    }),

                    contact:Em.Route.extend({
                        route:'/contact',
                        index:Em.Route.extend({
                            route:'/:contact_id',
                            deserialize:function (router, urlParams) {
                                return App.store.find(App.Contact, urlParams.contact_id);
                                debugger;
                            },

                            showEdit:function (router) {
                                router.transitionTo('contacts.contact.edit');
                            },

                            connectOutlets:function (router, context) {
                                if (router.get('applicationController').get('loggedin'))
                                    router.get('contactsController').connectOutlet('contact', context);
                                else   router.transitionTo('root.index');
                            }
                        }),

                        edit:Em.Route.extend({
                            route:'edit',

                            cancelEdit:function (router) {
                                router.transitionTo('contacts.contact.index');
                            },

                            connectOutlets:function (router) {
                                if (router.get('applicationController').get('loggedin')) {
                                    var contactsController = router.get('contactsController');
                                    contactsController.connectOutlet('editContact', router.get('contactController').get('content'));
                                    router.get('editContactController').enterEditing();
                                } else     router.transitionTo('root.index');
                            },

                            exit:function (router) {
                                router.get('editContactController').exitEditing();
                            }
                        })
                    }),
                    newContact:Em.Route.extend({
                        route:'/contacts/new',

                        cancelEdit:function (router) {
                            router.transitionTo('contacts.index');
                        },

                        connectOutlets:function (router) {
                            if (router.get('applicationController').get('loggedin')) {
                                router.get('contactsController').connectOutlet('editContact', {});
                                router.get('editContactController').enterEditing();
                            } else     router.transitionTo('root.index');
                        },

                        exit:function (router) {
                            router.get('editContactController').exitEditing();
                        }
                    })
                })*/
            })
        });
    }
);
```

EDIT #2

I changed the router now as follow, but it does not do anything.

```
define('routes/apps_router', ['ember'],
    function () {
        return Em.Router.extend({
            enableLogging:true
            ,location:'hash'

         ,map: function (match) {
            match("/").to("CategoryList", function (match) {
                match("/").to("mainNavigation");
            });
        }

        ,root:Ember.Route.extend({
            index:Ember.Route.extend({
                route:'/'

                ,renderTemplates: function() {
                    this.render('mainNavigation', {
                        into: 'CategoryList'
                    });
                }
           // ....
        });
    }
);
```

Kind regards,
Christopher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you use the latest release of ember with v2 router, you can do something like this:

```
App.Router.map(function (match) {
    match("/").to("categoryList", function (match) {
        match("/").to("foo");
    });
});
```

In your catergoryList template, put an {{outlet}} (you can optionally name it)

Then, your route for the template you want to insert into catergoryList will be like this:

```
App.fooRouter = Ember.Router.extend({
renderTemplates:function () {
        this.render('foo', {
            into:'catergoryList'
        });
    }
})
```

A good example of this in practice can be found here:  https://github.com/sh4n3d4v15/ember-todos

Comment: Shane, thanks for your answer. I added my app_router.js as well - because I can't yet adapt your approach to the current structure of my router. I copied the router.js from a example application.
And it seems like I should study the router section of the tutorial again to understand your answer correctly.

Comment: No worries, if I can help clarify anymore further on just let me know :)

Comment: While studying the router possibilities in more depth I found an approach using outlets in my router. Like:
connectOutlets:function (router) {  
router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('mainNavigation', 'CategoryList')  
}
Are there any disadvantages choosing this solution?

Comment: Hi Christopher, I'm afraid the Goal Posts have just moved on the learning curve of Ember-Router!haha the new router is not manually instantiated and the 'connectOutlets' function is deprecated in favour of the new 'renderTemplates' which allow you to specifiy which templates to load, into which parent template and a named outlet. If you could accept the above answer so others know that it is correct/relevant, we could discuss any problems you find with the v2 router seperately :)

Comment: Damn it, i was already so happy to get it working :-) OK then, so I must continue to understand your approach above..

Comment: HAHA, I was exactly the same, spent all week trying to master it when the router changed, but it is really good and well worth taking the time! I'll look out for any further questions you may have. :)

Comment: So I'm not the only one hehe. I added my current code (EDIT#2). But I neither get any error, nor any result. Actually I don't know exactly where to put the match-stuff. Can you give me a hint? Anyway, thank you already pretty much for your help!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22402/discussion-between-christopher-will-and-r-shane-davis)

Comment: Just wondering if I could have a look at your app Christopher. I am trying to do the same here but have pbs. Cheers